# How to pause or stop ionic youtube app playing in the background

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to stop playing youtube video in the background when I press home and screen lock buttons on my phone.

I am using iframe to load youtube video:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gvI2ClWqHO0" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

I used below code to stop but it failed:

```
ionViewWillLeave() {
this.platform.exitApp();
}
```

**Also how can I achevie the on click of Lock button when I pressed from my device?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I tried with Ionic Insomnia and it worked :

<code>
import { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia';

constructor(private insomnia: Insomnia) { }

...

this.insomnia.keepAwake()
  .then(
    () => console.log('success'),
    () => console.log('error')
  );

</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through JAVASCRIPT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can also transform that cod into angular service and use it.

for more information, see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Comment: I tried { Insomnia } from '@ionic-native/insomnia';. It worked

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic version 1

1. add inside

   ```
   app.run(function(){
   document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
               // cordova.plugins.backgroundMode is now available
               console.log("Device ready !!!");
           }, false);


       document.addEventListener("pause", function () {
           if ($rootScope.YTPlayer) {
               $rootScope.YTPlayer.stopVideo();
           }
       }, false);
   ```

   })

then Controller add

```
$scope.$on('youtube.player.ready', function ($event, player) {
                $rootScope.YTPlayer = player;
            });
```